# Migration to PHP8

Tags: php, migration, php-5.3, php-8

I have code from old PHP. 
But when I tried to execute it by PHP 8.

The first code was:

[PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/iRu2Uf4x)

I had error:

> Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces
> is no longer supported in **** on line 550

On line:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) $res .= ord($text{$i}) . "-";
```

I changed it to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) $res .= ord($text[$i]) . "-";
```

But I had another error:

> Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in ***
> on line 76

On line:

```
$real = $row['sip'];
```

I have no idea - how to rewrite this string.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to access a boolean value as you do with an array.

i imagine that $row is the result of a query, and that query does not return any matching rows, so it's false.

just check if $row is false before you access it.

```
<?php
$row = false;
echo $row['test'];
```

this returns that warning.

as per your comment, it depends on what you wanna do.

if it exist return the values, if it doesn't?

```
if($row){
// if it contains something, do something with it
}else{
// do something else if it doesn't
}
```

i don't know what's the flow of your code, so I can't really help you, it's just a check to see if the $row variable is not false

Comment: Thanks! Can you write - how can I do that, pls?